# Unable to get my App Approved from Microsoft App Store

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, office-store

Can anyone provide me the steps or the testing criteria which Microsoft App approval team is using?

I have tried 3 times to get my app approved from them but it is failing due to some design related issue. They have not reproted any functionality related or technical bugs though.

**So can you please provide some type of guidelines other than the Official guideline  provided by Microsoft?**

I have already gone through the guidelines provided by Microsoft for the SharePoint Addin.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/validation-policies

Is there anything else I need to consider?

If I want **how can I contact with Microsoft tester to get appropriate details of error or let them understand that they reported as a bug is actually not a bug?**

Comment: If your submission has failed three times in a row, then the validation team will have reached out to you via email within 24 hours of the third failure. Please check the email address on record for your account for this correspondence.

Comment: They have sent me the email as " Hi Team, 
 
Thank you for resubmitting your add-in to AppSource.  Unfortunately, your add-in continues to fail validation.  
 
Please see the attached report for details on the issues seen when attempting to use the add-in." from an email address "osdc1033@microsoft.com".  What should I say to them ask for a call to show them the functionality or what? Please guide

Comment: @SigarDave If the report does not reflect problem of your App you should email back and ask for clarifications. And from the email address, that means usually that sender is your case handler which should be able to work with you until problem solved. Like custom support, they have your case and they are helping you with your problem, just work with them to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At last I am able to get it approved you can visit that app here:

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104381785